# How to detect The end of togeling in a ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, events, reporting-services, toggle

I'm using SSRS Report Viewer in a WebForms Application. I have (+) icons that expand cells And I need to detect the exact moment when the Report Viewer finishs toggling. Any idea ? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by toggling ? Do you mean `drillthrough` one report to another ?

Comment: Here is link where you can add the event handler for the `Drillthrough` report toggling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.drillthrough.aspx. There is also one property `ReportViewer.ServerReport.IsDrillthroughReport` which detects if report is drill through

Comment: I have a report wich includes many total and subtotals columns. the user can expand columns to show details of subtotals. When the user refresh the report(call the stored procedure that is the datasource of the report), i need to postback the report with exactly the same state(columns that were expanded must be expanded). My idea is to loop throw icons(-) before calling server side then while posting back i'll expand them programmatically using javascript.is it clearer ?

Comment: Yes what I am asking is that if your (+) and (-) expansion is using drill trough or drill down report ? If it is drill trough report you can handle your requirement  it with just checking the `IsDrillthroughReport` property.